# Display Silverlight generated message

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

During full screen mode in silverlight it shows a following a message.

[image: silverlight Message]

First time i checked the "Remember my answer".
But now i need that message screen once again to display when i go to full-screen mode.
What i should do to get it. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this one, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/17/tip-trick-supporting-full-screen-mode-with-silverlight.aspx

Comment: @Sajeetharan : Thanks for reply. I don't think that solution will suit to my question. Any how thanks for your comment.

Comment: How about this? According to this page it will show the permissions and then you can remove them. It should ask again next time.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645084(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the plugin settings dialgoue, which looks like this:

[image]

You can get there by right-click your running application and select 'Silverlight' or from the start menu, click the Microsoft Silverlight folder.

On the permissions tab you can change this setting.